# AWS Auth parameters are overwritten in multiple env

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have different callback urls for each environment and if I use `amplify auth update` and fix the URL it still gets overwritten in `amplify/backend/auth/projectname/parameters.json` if I merge `master` into my `dev` branch and its quite frustrating. Not sure what the solution is.

Comment: a solution that worked for our team is to create a script overwriting the parameters.json when we want to build it in our CI/CD pipeline. I think Amplify does not have the capability to use different `parameters.json` for each env as of now. If you think it helps, I can provide you with a sample code.

Comment: That would be awesome, thank you so much! @kkesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, Amplify doesn't have any support for environment specific for `parameters.json`.

What worked for our team is we overwrite our `parameters.json` in our CI/CD pipeline (we only have different parameters for production environment)

so, we made a script (in node). This is an example of our custom config.

> Our solution depends on the amplify environment name. Currently, we use prod prefix for our production environments. So, you'll see something like `process.env.USER_BRANCH.startsWith('prod')`

config.json

```
module.exports = {
    'api': {
        filePath: 'amplify/backend/api/myproject/parameters.json',
        override: {
            production: {
                ElasticSearchInstanceCount: 3,
                ElasticSearchInstanceType: 't2.medium.elasticsearch'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

script.js (not a complete version)

```
if(!process.env.USER_BRANCH || !process.env.USER_BRANCH.startsWith('prod')) return
const parameter = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(config.filePath))
const overrideConfig = config.override['production']
fs.writeFileSync(config.filePath, JSON.stringify({
   ...parameter,
   ...overrideConfig
}))
```

and lastly, in your `amplify.yml`, run `node ./script.js` before `amplifyPush`. e.g.

```
version: 0.1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - node ./scripts/src/amplify-parameters-override/script.js
        - amplifyPush --simple
```